# Detect multiple category ID of a product in Virtuemart

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, virtuemart

We have such a statement that check if product is in this category then show some HTML but the problem is that this product is placed in multiple categories for example in fashion, men and sale so:

```
fashion category id is 16
men category id is 12
and sale category is 64
```

I try to identify if product is in category SALE as well in order to add some additional HTML but it works only if I set `if($this->product->virtuemart_category_id == 16)`

statement wich identify only first category

```
if($this->product->virtuemart_category_id == 64){

   echo 'your Custom HTML';
}
else{
 //nothing
}
```

HOw can we identify if this product is in SALE category too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

In VM You can add more than one category for a product,

It will give the category ids as an array like below.

```
print_r($this->product->categories );
```

So if you have predefined list of categories that required your custom styles.

```
if(in_array(16,$this->product->categories) || in_array(64,$this->product->categories) || in_array(12,$this->product->categories)){
echo 'your styles';
}
```

for more better method, you can try something like this

```
$custom_cats          = array(12,16,64);//your custom categories that required additional styles
$current_product_cats = $this->product->categories;
$checkstatus          = array_intersect($custom_cats , $current_product_cats);

if(sizeof($checkstatus)>0){ // check your first array element found in second array
echo 'your custom styles';
}
```

Hope its works..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `or` operator which is defined as `||`, like so:

```
$cat_id = $this->product->virtuemart_category_id;
if ($cat_id == 16 || $cat_id == 64) {
   echo 'your Custom HTML';
}
else {
   // do nothing
}
```

This detects if the category is **fashion** OR **sale**.

If you want to detect another category, simply add `|| $cat_id == ID`, where ID is the category ID

Hope this helps

Comment: it works but unfortunately it doesn't see that product is in category 64

Comment: do noot know why but product has only one id category probably

Comment: Most likely. I think in VirtueMart you can assign only 1 category to a product, not multiple ones